# Temp File Creation Error on GAE With PDFBox

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey, pdfbox

On GAE I am trying to update a PDF with a FDF file using PDFBox (and Jersey).

I have read on how you can't use PDFBox on GAE because certain classes aren't whitelisted. I was hoping that just populating the PDF from the FDF wouldn't cause an issue if none of these classes are called.

I haven't seen a whitelist issue yet but I am getting a "java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file"

So I am wondering if there is someway to avoid the FDFDocument creating the temp file?

Code!

```
package com.somecompany.test.service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;

@Path("/pdfboxtest")
public class PDFBoxTest {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response getFile() throws Exception {

        File pdfFile = new File("resources/GenerateFDF.pdf");
        File fdfFile = new File("resources/fdftest.fdf");

        PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        FDFDocument fdfDoc = FDFDocument.load(fdfFile);

        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDoc.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        acroForm.setCacheFields(true);
        acroForm.importFDF(fdfDoc);

        PDStream ps = new PDStream(pdfDoc);
        OutputStream outputStream = ps.createOutputStream();

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) outputStream);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=wellthatworked.pdf");
        return response.build();
    }
}
```

Full error log!

```html
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to create temporary file
 at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1873)
 at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1968)
 at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2013)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.createTmpFile(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:298)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.<init>(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:278)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.NonSequentialPDFParser.<init>(NonSequentialPDFParser.java:264)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFDocument.load(FDFDocument.java:200)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.fdf.FDFDocument.load(FDFDocument.java:172)
 at com.somecompany.test.service.PDFBoxTest.getFile(PDFBoxTest.java:31)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
 at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
 at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: IMHO it is a bug, i.e. the wrong constructor of NonSequentialParser is called. I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2644 for you. Could you please tell what version you are using, either here or in that issue (you need to register)?

Comment: To me it looks like that would be the stack trace for 1.8.8. Indeed, both file based `FDFDocument.load` overloads `load(String)` and `load(String)` create `FileInputStream` instances and use `load( InputStream` which in turn uses a `NonSequentialPDFParser` constructed in a way to copy that stream into a temp file first. Usually this merely is a nuisance, but in the context of GAE it is a blocker.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I am using version 1.8.8. I am going to look at other ways of solving this problem. The use of the FDF would be convenient but not absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed version will be available in 1.8.9. However you can already test it now by going here
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.9-SNAPSHOT/
(get a jar file from January 30 21:54 or later).

If it works, press the green checkmark or just delete the question. If it doesn't work, please write a comment.

Note that you may get into more trouble, I heard that GAE has other restrictions, see the discussion [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1027).

Comment: Yes other problems did occur and I had to seek another solution but thanks for your help and the fix!

Comment: Hei Doug, what were the other problems? How you've fixed it in the end?